# Ruby: How to replace the words in string by two arrays?

Tags: ruby

My case:

```
text = "[A] and [B]"
search = ["[A]", "[B]", "[C]", "[D]", "[Aa]"]
replace = ["[B]", "[C]", "[D]", "[E]", "[Bb]"]
```

i want to replace value of `text` to `"[B] and [C]"`

How can i do that? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
text.gsub(/\[\w+\]/, Hash[search.zip replace])
# => "[B] and [C]"
```

Comment: Thank you! it seem good. can i ask more? i have this case: `text = "[A#] and [B]"`, `search = ["[A#]", "[B]", "[C]", "[D]", "[Aa]"]`, `replace = ["[B]", "[C]", "[D]", "[E]", "[Bb]"]`, and i still want to replace value of text to `"[B] and [C]"`.
How can i modify your method to use it?

Comment: Just add `#` to gsub part, like this: `.gsub(/\[\w+\#*\]/,`

Comment: Thank you @YevgeniyAnfilofyev, i tried to use `.gsub(/\[\w+#\]/,` and i forgot `*` after `#`

Comment: Another option is to build the regular expression from the input array: `text.gsub(Regexp.union(search), search.zip(replace).to_h)`

Comment: This is a great answer, as is @Stefan's comment which makes it work for arbitrary search strings.